# Google Sheets: How to eliminate duplicates in some columns and show only the most recent data in others?

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I have a spreadsheet of books, with one row for every time a book was checked out (this is a small classroom library). Here are the columns:

```
BookTitle        | Author        | DateCheckedOut | CheckedOutBy | Status
=========================================================================
The BFG          | Dahl, Roald   | 6/1/2016       | Suzy         | Out
The BFG          | Dahl, Roald   | 4/5/2016       | Johnny       | Returned
The BFG          | Dahl, Roald   | 12/4/2015      | Wendy        | Returned
Charlotte's Web  | White, E.B.   |                |              | Added
Wonder           | Palacio, R.J. | 5/29/2016      | Joey         | Returned
Wonder           | Palacio, R.J. | 3/21/2016      | Mary         | Returned
```

I want to query it to get only the row with the highest date value for each book and then display all columns of that row except CheckedOutBy.

I wanted to get a list of unique book title / author combinations and then join it with the original table the way I would in DB2, but it seems that joins like that are not possible in Google Sheets. I tried grouping and the max function, but when I get those things to work I either haven't been able to eliminate earlier dates or haven't been able to display columns that aren't being used in the aggregate function. My Google Sheets querying skills are not up to par :/

Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing? I would appreciate any tips.

Here's a copy of that sample data from above in a Google Sheet.:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J384S0fsc8tgxVMehPb_uyRNc5-6cQx-xKN-q8K8Gds/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a new sheet and entered in cell A1

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(Sheet1!A2:A), sort(Sheet1!A2:E, 3, 0), {1, 2, 3, 5}, 0)))
```

See if that works for you ?

BREAKDOWN:

The general idea behind the formula is to make use of the fact that VLOOKUP only returns the first match. We want that 'first match' to be the latest date per book.

1. So first we sort the table so that the latest dates are on top.
2. We 'lookup' the unique book titles in that sorted table and we return the columns {1, 2, 3, 5}.

Links:

- [sort() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150)
- [vlookup() function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response -- that seems to do the trick :)

So I get the general idea of what's happening. If I want to eliminate any problems related to two books having the same title, could I change "A2:A" to "A2:B"?

Also, there are two zeroes in that formula. What do they each do?

Comment: The first zero in the sort is to indicate we want to sort descending. The second zero (in the vlookup) is to indicate that we use a 'sorted' lookup table (and there want to have an exact match). Instead of those zeroes you can also use 'FALSE'. I'm not sure I understand what you mean with the change from A2:A to A2:B since book titles are in col A, right ?